# L.polygon boundings in leafletjs

Tags: geolocation, leaflet

I have several markers in a map, I want to color the area inside the maps of a different color. I've tried L.multiPolygon , L.polygon, L.rectangle, but nothing does but I want. I guess my only option is to calculate the boundings of all the markers and draw the polygon based on these points, right ?

Here the code

```
<c:forEach var="marker" items="${markers}" varStatus="rowIndex">
        var marker${rowIndex.index} = L.marker([${marker.lat},${marker.lng}],{icon: yellowIcon,title: '${marker.title}'}).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup( "${marker.HTMLMarkerPopupCode}").openPopup();
        storeCoordinate(${marker.lat}, ${marker.lng}, polygonPoints);
</c:forEach>

 var polygon = L.polygon(polygonPoints);

polygon.setStyle({fillColor: '#0000FF'});
polygon.setStyle({color: 'red'});
polygon.setStyle({weight:1});   
polygon.setStyle({fillOpacity: 0.5});
mymap.addLayer(polygon);
```

[image]

I would like to achieve something similar to this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use L.Polygon as well.

Just do something like this:

```
var polygon = L.polygon([
    marker1,
    marker2,
    marker3,
], {
   fillColor: '#f03' // My custom color here
}
).addTo(mymap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve?

You might be interested in computing the [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your markers area.

In that case, you should be able to find some JavaScript implementations on the Internet. E.g., you can look at how it is done in Leaflet.markercluster plugin: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/src/MarkerCluster.QuickHull.js

---

EDIT:

As for creating Convex Hull, you could also use [Turf](http://turfjs.org/), in particular [`turf.convex`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#convex).

Turf also provides you with plenty other functionalities, including [`turf.concave`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#concave).